# Android - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.Maps.HomeScreen

Tags: java, android

I have just opened my code from a few weeks off and now it doesn't seem to work. I have a splash screen on open, which then moves to the home screen. The splash screen works, but when trying to move to the home page it falls over saying `No Class Def Found`. What does this mean and how can i fix it?

It says the problem is found with the below code which is in the splash screen class:

```
 public void run()
        {
         //Finish the splash activity so it can't be returned to.
         SplashScreen.this.finish();
         // Create an Intent that will start the main activity.
         Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
         SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
         }
```

Comment: Ru trying to run in emulator without google api?

Answer (score 0):

please place HomeScreen in manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".HomeScreen"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what happened was I updated the Android SDK and apparently there have been a few problems with this, one being changing lib to libs. What I did was removed the activity and re-added. Thanks arcastro.

So if anyone has this problem from 16->17, check the activity's in the manifest file, and the lib folder